# Does the Sony Add on SDK 2.0 work with the previous sony smartwatch?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

Does the Sony Add on SDK 2.0 work only with the new smartwatch 2 or does it work with the previous sony  smartwatch? If yes, then can I access the light sensor in sw 1 using that just like we can do in sw 2? Also, is the touch still only limited to tap and swipe and long press for the second sdk/sw 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sony Add-on SDK 2.0 is compatible with both Sony SmartWatch and Sony SmartWatch 2.

There is no support for the light sensor on the Sony SmartWatch. As such, you will only be able to access this on Sony SmartWatch 2.

Apart from the three methods you mention, you will also have the option to implement onClick and onLongClick listeners in layouts.